# Do I need to say “o’clock”?

Tags: time

Do I need to say “o’clock” after each time? Tell me, please, how to pronounce the following sentence:

> From 9.00 to 10.00 - registration of conference participants

And how to say:

> From 12.00 - to 14.00

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. When it is clear you are talking about a time (as it is here) "o'clock" is optional, and often omitted.

So "From 9 to 10" would be the common way of reading that.

Your second example is most commonly "From 12 to 2".

Comment: I agree that in a schedule they are likely to be **written** "from 9:00 to 10:00", but **pronounced** "from 9 to 10". In a schedule anywhere outside the US, they are likely to use a 24 hour clock, not a.m. and p.m.

Comment: I agree that you could just say "from nine to ten".

You could also say "from nine to ten o'clock", with the "o'clock" implicitly applying to both. I might say that (instead of "from nine to ten"), if I wanted to make clear that I'm talking about times. If one of them has minutes, that implies that they are times, so you could normally leave off the "o'clock" from the other one: "from nine-thirty to ten", or "from ten to eleven-thirty".

It's also ok to say "o'clock" when it's not needed, like "from nine o'clock to ten o'clock", "from nine o'clock to ten thirty", but it sounds more formal.

Comment: @GlennWillen You can also use the "o'clock" for emphasis of punctuality:  "be here at 9" is far more casual about the time than "be here at 9 o'clock" or "be here on the dot of 9" (the latter implying that even 09:01 is too late!)

Comment: I would add to this - certainly where I live, it would be more common to say "from 9 *until* 10", or "from 9 'til 10".  If you say "from 10 to 11", it can create confusion over whether you mean starting at 10:00 and ending at 11:00, or starting at 10:50...

Comment: In the UK, I don't think I've ever heard anyone say "fourteen" for a time. It would always be "2pm" or (since 2am is very unsociable) just "2 (o'clock)". You could explicitly say "2am" to emphasize a very early or late time.

Comment: @GlennWillen In the UK (or at least the small part of England that I've lived in), saying "ten to eleven" when the time is 10:50 would be extremely common ("ten minutes to eleven" would sound oddly formal). Context has always been sufficient to differentiate that from the time period between 10:00 and 11:00.

Comment: /me sings Dolly Parton's hit song _Nine to Five_ and smiles.

Comment: @MontyHarder I went straight to "twenty-five or six to four" by Chicago which is fairly hard to recognize as a time if you are just listening to the song without any context.  I didn't realize it was a time for years.

Comment: @Chronocidal I've never heard "o'clock" used to emphasize punctuality before; "9 on the dot" is common, but "be here at 9" and "be here at 9 o'clock" are exactly the same semantically, at least in my vernacular.

Comment: @BillK Huge Chicago fan here  I should have thought of that too, but like you I was confused. For a long time, I thought it was "25 (years old) or 6 (minutes) to 4 (am)", comparing "what time is it (in my life/in the day)" before realizing it's really "25 or (2)6 (minutes)..."

Answer (score 6):

In the US, 14:00 is typically only used by the military (and would be said "fourteen hundred" or sometimes "fourteen hundred hours", while 9:00 would be "oh nine hundred:).  For civilians, it would be said "twelve to two" or "noon to two" with "PM" (usually uppercase) added if there's possible confusion about the event lasting until 2:00 AM.

In a written schedule, it could most efficiently be written "9:00 - 10:00" and "12:00 - 2:00", with the ":00" possibly omitted if everything starts on the hour.

Comment: The armed forces has their own lingo. Doing something by Yankee time means you are effing late. ASAP Yankee, meant not now, but NOW, DAMMIT!

Comment: Speaking the words 'ten **TO** two' is equally likely to cause confusion! 'Ten **TILL** two' makes more sense.

Comment: In a program schedule for a conference, you will most definitely have am and pm written out. The 24-hour thing is irrelevant to the question in any case.

Comment: @Tim I hear "from ten to two", meaning starting at 10am and ending at 2pm, pretty much every day. In the US, I think "till/'til" is fairly uncommon (today - it was more common in the past). jamesqf - note that when military, airline, etc. 24 hour time is used in the US, it's most proper to omit the colon, as in "1400" or "0900".

Comment: @ToddWilcox - my problem with that is can be misconstrued as 'from one fifty' (ten mins to two o'clock) As often happens, the pond's got in the way..!

Comment: @Tim: It can't be interpreted as "from one fifty" because then there's no second time. You would have an open-ended time period, and by context it's obvious that's not what is intended.

Comment: @Tim - on an English language learning site, I would steer clear of advising the use of abbreviations. If you think "to" is ambiguous, use "until" (not "till" - which means a cash register).

Comment: @Chris Melville: Well, MAYBE it means a cash register.  Could be the rocks & dirt left behind by a glacier, or the act of preparing soil for planting, or...

Comment: @jamesqf - Very true. You're a pedant... and I like it :)